# HttpClient returning wrong csv?

Tags: android, parsing, csv

Hi I've been trying to download a csv from http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=msft&f=sl1p2 and have been trying to subsequently parse the data. Here's the code below. It's currently returning just the html header in the toast. Any ideas why it's not returning the actual results in the csv?

```
    Stock stock = new Stock();
    try {

        //need to call yahoo api and get csv -> parse csv for most recent price and price change
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        String result = "";

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){

              result += line + "\n";
              String[] RowData = result.split("\n");
              Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              String name = RowData[0];
              String price = RowData[1];
              String change = RowData[2];

              stock.setPrice(Double.parseDouble(price));
              stock.setTicker(name);
              stock.setChange(change);


            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you need to `split` on a comma rather than a newline?

```
String[] RowData = result.split(",");
```

When I run the code using the above, and replacing the Toast with

```
System.out.println("result = "+ result);
```

I get:

```
result = "MSFT",24.80,"+0.08%"
```

and the values of `name`, `price` and `change` are populated successfully.  I don't see a header line at all.

Please note that Java convention is that variable names start with a lowercase letter, so `rowData` not `RowData`.

Comment: yes, this was the solution. figured it out too :). I also needed to use the replaceAll to get rid of the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=msft&f=sl1p2
```

the url you are providing is containing two arguments:

```
1: s=msft
   -this is the yahoo finance api code for microsoft

2: f=sl1p2 
   - this contains 3 sub-parameters
   - s [it is the company name]
   - l1 [it is the company's last quote price]
   - p2 [it is the price change]
```

So i guess the CSV that you are getting is correct.

Comment: i have a php code snippet for the same. if you want then i can share it with you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function getStockSite($stockLink){

   if ($fp = fopen($stockLink, 'r')) {
      $content = '';

      while ($line = fread($fp, 1024)) {
         $content .= $line;
      }
   }

   return $content;  
}

?>

<table cellpadding="0" style="width:700px;" cellspacing="0">

<tr>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Indices</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Prev. Price</th>
<th>High</th>
<th>Low</th>
<th>Change</th>
</tr>


<?php

$url="http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=^BSESN&f=d1p5phgc6";
try
{
$data = getStockSite($url);
$bse=explode(",",$data);
}
catch(exception $e)
{
}
?>

<tr>
<td>INDIA</td>
<td>SENSEX</td>
<td><?php echo $bse[0];?></td>
<td><?php echo $bse[1];?></td>
<td><?php echo $bse[2];?></td>
<td><?php echo $bse[3];?></td>
<td><?php echo $bse[4];?></td>
<td><?php echo $bse[5];?></td>
<tr>


</table>
```